# Getting US equity data for commercial use?

Tags: equities, market-data, historical-data

If you were a hobbyist in the process of building a subscription site that people are willing to pay for, how would you get US equity data in a commercially available form?

I just need EOD delayed price data on US equities, no fundamentals or additional data.

I know that you can contact data providers, but I assume the Reuters/Bloombergs of the world don't have the time for a minnow like myself, and they'd probably be too expensive anyhow. Anyone know of some reasonably priced solutions where the price scales with the project so I can smartly allocate time to talking to the salespeople and not waste their time if my project doesn't meet their size criteria?

Any idea of how the pricing structure works? Apologies for my ignorance, but I've never worked with financial data on the commercial level before.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Who exactly is willing to pay for delayed EOD us equity prices? That data is freely available on all sorts of websites and APIs.

Comment: @AKdemy Yes it's available for free, but not for commercial use. FYI, I'm not reselling the data lol, it's just a part of a software product where a 15-min delay is de-minimus. I'm looking for data similar to that you can get from Yahoo, etc., but where I can buy a commercial license.

Answer (score 1):

maybe the products of [iex cloud](https://iexcloud.io/) will suit your project.

Comment: Thank you very much! Turns out IEX offers a business plan that allows commercial use (https://intercom.help/iexcloud/en/articles/4856525-how-to-use-our-individual-and-business-plan) out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I use this myself and is very good for back testing also.

https://norgatedata.com/stockmarketpackages.php#usstocks